# How to reach Caffeine settings

Tags: settings, caffeine

According to https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Caffeine/ there should appear a settings dialog, after rightclicking the Caffeine symbol. That does not work for me with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and Caffeine 2.9.4
How can I reach the settings?

[Caffeine settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3puO.png)

[image]

Comment: Choose Einstellungen from the drop down menu.

Comment: I`d like to do so, but it doesn`t show up in the dropdown menu. I only get Deactivate/Activate, Info, Beenden.

Comment: See https://bugs-launchpad-net.translate.goog/caffeine/+bug/1700419?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=ajax,se,elem

Comment: @Puh, please make actual screenshot from your Ubuntu version and insert it to question. What is your desktop environment?

Comment: Done. Could it be that the settings option has been removed by the developer?

Comment: This item seems to be removed. Could you please tell us the source of [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3puO.png)? I suspect it from 2010s.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the historical source code analysis. The changelog file [indicates](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Ecaffeine-developers/caffeine/main/view/head:/debian/changelog#L176) that the Preferences was removed from Caffeine 2.5:

> caffeine (2.5) saucy; urgency=low
>
> - Remove --preferences command-line option, no longer needed.

So we need to get older Caffeine 2.4.1 version from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecaffeine-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) with old dependencies by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/caffeine_2.4.1+478~raring1_all.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_12.10.1daily13.04.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/multiarch-support_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/python-appindicator_12.10.1daily13.04.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-central/python-central_0.6.17ubuntu2_all.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/notify-python/python-notify_0.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libd/libdvdread/libdvdread4_4.2.0+20121016-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kaa-base/python-kaa-base_0.6.0+svn4596-1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kaa-metadata/python-kaa-metadata_0.7.7+svn4596-4_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./caffeine_2.4.1+478~raring1_all.deb  ./python-central_0.6.17ubuntu2_all.deb ./python-appindicator_12.10.1daily13.04.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python-notify_0.1.1-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python-kaa-metadata_0.7.7+svn4596-4_amd64.deb ./libdvdread4_4.2.0+20121016-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ./libappindicator1_12.10.1daily13.04.15-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python-kaa-base_0.6.0+svn4596-1_amd64.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./multiarch-support_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb python-dbus
```

and then Caffeine will show (at least on MATE, the fork of GNOME 2.3x) its Preferences as it was in 2013:

[image: Caffeine on MATE]

This old Caffeine version maybe locked at its version by using the long command below:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-caffeine
Package: caffeine
Pin: version 2.4.1+478~raring1
Pin-Priority: 1337

Package: libappindicator1
Pin: version 12.10.1daily13.04.15-0ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

If you do not like it, then revert to modern version by using

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-caffeine
sudo dpkg -P --force-all python-central
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

---

Please note that 1.0.1 version from 2009 with "Activate for" submenu is not installable because of very old dependencies.

---

If anyone knows the replacement of Caffeine for modern GNOME please write an answer covering this. Brief search gives a clue that `gnome-shell-extension-caffeine` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-shell-extension-caffeine) maybe a good replacement for original Caffeine.

Comment: Thanx @NOrbert, I installed it as you suggested. Unfortunately, on my system the icon does not appear at all, when I start caffeine 2.4.1. Maybe this is the reason for the changes from version 2.5 onwards.